# Adding a space to array output

Tags: jquery

**GOAL**

I am gathering the text values of each navigation item and storing it in a variable. I then compare that variable to a set value variable so I can do something with those that match.

**ISSUE**

The first variable is outputting the navigation text when I run an console log, but they're all smashed together so the query never matches the set variable.

**THE CODE**

```
$( ".item_text" ).each(function() {
    var text = $('.item_text').text() + " ";
    var comparingText = 'Shop'

    if(text == comparingText){
          $('.item_text').css('display','none');
    };

    // console.log(text);
});
```

I've left in the + " " as it was what I thought would accomplish this, but the output is still smushed together.

Comment: Your logic suffers from repeated global selectors

Comment: Please elaborate, thank you.

Comment: The important take away from both of our answers is the usage of `$(this)`.  When you do `$('.item_text')` inside your each, you are repeatedly selecting *every* element again and again.  When you get text(), iirc, it will return the text for all the fields.  And it definitely will hide them all when you do `hide()` on them.  So you want to avoid that if you are trying to change individual elements base upon a status they have.

Comment: Ah, thank you for that explanation. I am new to jQuery so this information is very helpful!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of that, use `.indexOf()` to find if that part of string exists and then you can apply `hide()` on it:

```js
$(function () {
  var compareText = "Hello";
  $( ".item_text" ).filter(function () {
    return $(this).text().trim() === compareText;
  }).hide();
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="item_text">Hello</div>
<div class="item_text">World</div>
```

Make sure that the `.item_text` is there only in places, where it's necessary. This will target all the elements with the class `class="item_text"`.

Comment: `text` would be better rather than `html`.

Comment: @Oen44 Sure. Updating.

Comment: And it will hide every `.item_text` that contains `Hello` word. Even `Hello World` or `foobarHellobarfoo`. You should compare string in this case. `return $(this).text().trim() === compareText;`

Answer (score 1):

```js
$( ".item_text" ).each(function() {
    //get the text for just the element being iterated over
    var text = $(this).text();
    var comparingText = 'Shop';

    if(text == comparingText){
      //same thing here
      $(this).hide();
    };
});

//however this could also be done with a filter

$( '.item_text' ).filter(function(){
  return $(this).text() === 'Shop';
}).hide();
```